# How does "imagettfbbox()" in PHP work?

Tags: php, gd

Could you please explain what exactly the return value of `imagettfbbox()` mean? [The manual says](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php#refsect1-function.imagettfbbox-returnvalues):

> imagettfbbox() returns an array with 8 elements representing four
>   points making the bounding box of the text on success and FALSE on
>   error. [...Table of points here...]
>   The points are relative to the text regardless of the angle, so "upper
>   left" means in the top left-hand corner seeing the text horizontally.

But, I found it not very clear. For example, the return value:

```
array(-1, 1, 61, 1, 61, -96, -1, -96)
```

means the following points:

```
(-1, -96) ------ (61, -96)
    |                |
    |                |
    |                |
    |                |
    |                |
    |                |
 (-1, 1) -------- (61, 1)
```

How should I interpret them?

Why there are negative values?

Comment: what params did you pass to the function?

Comment: just see it as a Cartesian grid

Answer (score 13):

You should take a look at the [comment by "marclaz" on the `imagettfbbox` manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php#68518) :

> Please note that as imageTTFBbox and imageTTFText functions return an
>   array of coordinates which could be negative numbers care must be
>   taken with height and width calculations.
>
> The rigth way to do that is to use the abs() function:
>
> for an horizontal text:
>
> ```
> $box = @imageTTFBbox($size,0,$font,$text); $width = abs($box[4] -
> $box[0]); $height = abs($box[5] - $box[1]);
> ```
>
> Then to center your text at ($x,$y) position the code should be like
>   that:
>
> ```
> $x -= $width/2; $y += $heigth/2;
>
> imageTTFText($img,$size,0,$x,$y,$color,$font,$text);
> ```
>
> this because (0,0) page origin is topleft page corner and (0,0) text
>   origin is lower-left readable text corner.

Comment: _"this because (0,0) page origin is topleft page corner and (0,0) text origin is lower-left readable text corner."_ Is this difference in origin a standard in graphics design or a PHP-ism?

Comment: Downvote. _"The rigth way to do that is to use the abs() function"_ This is wrong. The correct way to do it is `$width = $box[2] - $box[0]` (without the `abs()`). Otherwise if a character extends to the left of its 0 position the width will come out lower than it should. I don't understand why this answer has so many upvotes. For instance, if a character's leftmost position is -2 and its rightmost position is 5, its width is therefore 7. If you use `abs()` its width will come out as 3.

Answer (score 1):

The following resource explains this:
[http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/11/2/6 (via archive.org)](http://web.archive.org/web/20120917063647/http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/11/2/6)

Just use [abs()](http://www.php.net/abs). This is from the resource above: "[the function] returns its values from the lower-left corner of the baseline of the text string, not the absolute lower-left corner. The baseline of a letter is where it would sit if you were hand writing it on lined paper"

Comment: The linked page incorrectly uses `abs` on the individual coordinate values instead of *after* doing math on them.  Doing that is going to result in misalignments,

Comment: @Charles Now the link is broken, so problem solved? 

Comment: @totymedli Oh, thanks for noticing that.  I've found a copy of the bad article on archive.org and updated the link in the post.  It remains incorrect.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Alain Tiemblo and Charles only partly worked for me, a few characters, like '1' weren't pixel perfect.

But the [comment of blackbart at simail dot it](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php#97357) on the same page worked very nice:

> I wrote a simple function that calculates the *exact* bounding box (single pixel precision). 
>   The function returns an associative array with these keys: 
>   left, top:  coordinates you will pass to imagettftext 
>   width, height: dimension of the image you have to create
>
> `function calculateTextBox($font_size, $font_angle, $font_file, $text) {
>       $box   = imagettfbbox($font_size, $font_angle, $font_file, $text);
>       if( !$box )
>           return false;
>       $min_x = min( array($box[0], $box[2], $box[4], $box[6]) );
>       $max_x = max( array($box[0], $box[2], $box[4], $box[6]) );
>       $min_y = min( array($box[1], $box[3], $box[5], $box[7]) );
>       $max_y = max( array($box[1], $box[3], $box[5], $box[7]) );
>       $width  = ( $max_x - $min_x );
>       $height = ( $max_y - $min_y );
>       $left   = abs( $min_x ) + $width;
>       $top    = abs( $min_y ) + $height;
>       // to calculate the exact bounding box i write the text in a large image
>       $img     = @imagecreatetruecolor( $width << 2, $height << 2 );
>       $white   =  imagecolorallocate( $img, 255, 255, 255 );
>       $black   =  imagecolorallocate( $img, 0, 0, 0 );
>       imagefilledrectangle($img, 0, 0, imagesx($img), imagesy($img), $black);
>       // for sure the text is completely in the image!
>       imagettftext( $img, $font_size,
>           $font_angle, $left, $top,
>           $white, $font_file, $text);
>       // start scanning (0=> black => empty)
>       $rleft  = $w4 = $width<<2;
>       $rright = 0;
>       $rbottom   = 0;
>       $rtop = $h4 = $height<<2;
>       for( $x = 0; $x < $w4; $x++ )
>           for( $y = 0; $y < $h4; $y++ )
>               if( imagecolorat( $img, $x, $y ) ){
>                   $rleft   = min( $rleft, $x );
>                   $rright  = max( $rright, $x );
>                   $rtop    = min( $rtop, $y );
>                   $rbottom = max( $rbottom, $y );
>               }
>       // destroy img and serve the result
>       imagedestroy( $img );
>       return array( "left"   => $left - $rleft,
>           "top"    => $top  - $rtop,
>           "width"  => $rright - $rleft + 1,
>           "height" => $rbottom - $rtop + 1 );
>   }`