# How to write text to images with different sizes using PHP GD

Tags: php, gd, image-manipulation

I'm creating images with different sizes. How can I write text on those images so that the texts always fit to the images?

```php
$text = "some text as example";
$font = "arialbd.ttf"
$fontsize = 26;
offset_x = 0;
offset_y = 0;

$image01 = imagecreate( 1120 , 900 );
$image02 = imagecreate( 400 , 300 ); 
$image03 = imagecreate( 1120 , 900 );
```

I know that there is the `imagefttext` function that can apply text to the images but with that function I can only change the font size to make the text bigger. How can I find out that it fits into my image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to scale the font size so that text string fills the image width, try this.
Using imagettfbbox, determine the current text box width:

```
 $bbox = imagettfbbox($fontsize,0,$fontpath,$string);
 $tbwidth = $bbox[2];
```

Then divide the image width by the $tbwidth to get a factor

```
 $factor = round(($imgwidth / $tbwidth), 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN); //ie. 800/240=3
```

Multiple the $factor by you $fontsize to get an approximate increase.

```
 $newfontsize = $fontsize * $factor; //ie. 12(pt) * 3 = 36
```

Keep in minds, if you're using GD 2.0, fontsize is in Points and not pixels.  Your algorithm is going to calculate the difference between your default font size text box (expressed as a text box width) and the image width.

Comment: Keep in mind that [`imagettfbbox`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php#68518) returns a coordinate array that can have negative values. A better width calculation is `abs($bbox[2] - $bbox[0])` like said in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12338251/1494454).

Comment: Nice solution, but passing `0` as precision for `round()` gives inaccurate results. If I have a 400px width text on a 500px width image, it will round down and return `1.0`, thus not adjusting the font size. I suggest a higher precision or, even better, drop the rounding. Just use `$imgwidth / $tbwidth`.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Set the content-type
header('Content-Type: image/png');

// Create the image
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(800, 600);

// Create some colors
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
imagefill($im, 0, 0, $white);

// The text to draw
$text = 'Testing...';
// Replace path by your own font path
$font_file = 'arial.ttf';
$font_size = '15';

$bbox   = imageftbbox($font_size, 0, $font_file, $text);

$width  = $bbox[2] - $bbox[6];
$height = $bbox[3] - $bbox[7];

// Add the text
imagettftext($im, $font_size, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font_file, $text);

// Using imagepng() results in clearer text compared with imagejpeg()
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Comment: please look at this [link](http://s25.postimg.org/3ntwk477z/da_php.png).it is still not on complete image it just shown at top. i want that text completely cover all image that you create `$im = imagecreatetruecolor(800, 600);`

Answer (score 1):

I recently came across the same situation with transparent backgrounds but the current examples are either not a solution but clues or a solution that doesn't work, so hereby a combined and working solution if anyone need it.

```
function imagecreater($width = 600, $height = 600) {

    //Create an empty transparent image
    $img = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    imagealphablending($img, false);
    imagesavealpha($img, true);
    $transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($img, 255, 255, 255, 127);
    imagefill($img, 0, 0, $transparent);

    //Text information
    $text = "some text as example";
    $font = "arialbd.ttf"
    $fontsize = 26; //default font to be altered later


    //simulate a complete text box and get the width
    $bbox = imageftbbox($fontsize, 0, $font, $text);
    $tbwidth = $bbox[2]; 

    //Calculate different between our transparent image and text box
    //I've added a little padding (20px) since the text sometimes crossing the edge.. 
    $factor = (($width - 20) / $tbwidth);

    //Alter font size with difference to fit fully image
    $newfontsize = $fontsize * $factor;

    //Find the horisontal center
    $bbox = imageftbbox($newfontsize, 0, $font, $text);
    $newheight = ($height / 2) + (($bbox[3] - $bbox[7]) / 2);

    //Set Color of text
    $color = imagecolorallocate($img, 200, 0, 0);

    //Produce our image
    imagettftext($img, $newfontsize, 0, 0, $newheight, $color, $font, $text);

    //Copy image to file and free the cached image
    $target = "testimage.png";
    imagepng($img, $target);
    imagedestroy($img);
}
```

As *rwhite35* mentioning here, please keep in mind that GD 2.0 write font size is in points and not pixels.

Comment: Thank you.. but text aligns more left than right. you can notice the text aligns 2px more left side.

Answer (score 0):

Use the imageftbbox function to get the size of the bounding box of the text. You can then adjust the text size to fit the size of the image exactly.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imageftbbox.php